# Remove all ocurrences of some characters between patterns in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that contains a somehow bad translation of PHP code to TWIG, I need to remove only the first and last occurence of parenthesis () and any occurence of $ that is enclosed between {% and %} tags

For example if in the file there is:

```
{% if($var.has($something)) %}
This symbols ($($)$) won't be deleted becoase they aren't between {% and %}
```

I need that get transformed into:

```
{% if var.has( something) %}
This symbols ($($)$) won't be deleted becoase they aren't between {% and %}
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How accurate do you need it? If you don't have multiple {% %} {% %} on a single line (or if you can `s/%}/&\n/g` to prevent that), you could use the horrifyingly ugly

```
sed -e ':s; s/{%\(.*\)\$\(.*\)%}/{%\1\2%}/; ts; s/{%\([^(]*\)(\(.*\))\(.*\)%}/{%\1 \2 \3%}/'
```

It removes all `$`s inside `{% %}`, and then the outermost parenthesis if any.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I wanted. Now I'm making a very big coffe that helps me endure to find out how that horrifyingly ugly command works :p

Answer (score 1):

When syntax is involved I like to use `vim` for that task. In your case:

vim -c '%g/{%/norm /(^[ma%x`ar ' file

Explanation:
- vim -c - run command

- %g     - for each line
- /{%    - containing pattern {%
- norm   - entrer vim normal mode
- /(     - go to (
- ^{     - ESC (press CTRL+V< FOLLOWED BY ESC)
- ma     - mark current location as 'a'
- %      - go to matching closing )
- x      - remove it
- `a     - go back to (
- r      - replace it to space

Comment: Thank you for answering but I needed a command like the one "that other guy" shared for doing the job in a bash script.
Thank you in addition for teaching the commands of Vim, it's part of my study TODO's thing